# Use Nlopt Library in a Fortran project with Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, fortran, nlopt

I have been using the [NLopt library](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Image:Nlopt-logo.png) in my Fortran projects and I have no problem running it under Linux system. Now I just started using the Visual studio on Windows to write my Fortran programs. However, I am having some difficulties to use the NLopt library on Windows. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Intel Parallel Studio XE 17 on my computer.

Here are what I have done and the problems that I have encountered:

1. I downloaded the Windows version (64 bit) of NLopt library from its website. Then I use the developer command prompt for VS to execute `lib /def:libnlopt-0.def \MACHINE:x64` and it creates a .lib and .exp file under the same folder.
2. I created a Fortran project in Visual Studio with and use the code that was been working under Linux. In Visual Studio, I added the path to the .lib and .exp to "Additional Include Directories" and "Additional Library Directories" to the project property. I also added "libnlopt-0.lib" and "libnlopt-0.exp" to "Additional Dependencies".
3. When I compile the project, it fails with the errors:

   ```
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_CREATE referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_FTOL_ABS referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_FTOL_REL referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_XTOL_ABS referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_XTOL_REL referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_LOWER_BOUNDS referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_UPPER_BOUNDS referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_SET_MAX_OBJECTIVE referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_ADD_INEQUALITY_CONSTRAINT referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_OPTIMIZE referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   1>mod_nlopt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol NLO_DESTROY referenced in function MOD_NLOPT_mp_SUB_NLOPT
   ```
4. Then I followed the suggestions [here] (http://nlopt-discuss.ab-initio.mit.narkive.com/M3vzZMYA/nlopt-linked-to-intel-fortran-compiler-for-windows) and added `/names:lowercase` to the command line and now it compiles fine but with one warning:

   ```
   libnlopt-0.exp : warning LNK4070: /OUT:libnlopt-0.dll directive in .EXP differs from output filename 'x64\Release\baseline.exe'; ignoring directive
   ```
5. Although it compiles fine, I still cannot run my compiled code. When I run it, my computer tells me that `This APP cannot run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software published`. Then the command window shows `Access denied` and then the program stops.

I really do not know what I can do next to make my code work. I know there are many people use NLopt in Windows.

Comment: Which Windows version do you have? Is it 64-bit? How do your compilation commands look like?

Comment: I am using 64 bit version of Windows 10. The compilation is done by Visuao Studio using the standard compilation options except with `/names:lowercase` option mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution. For the second step above, I should only put "libnlopt-0.lib", but not "libnlopt-0.exp" to "Additional Dependencies" in Visual Studio project property. After that, I copied "libnlopt-0.dll" to the working directory of my program. Then my program can run without any problem!